# Getting better control on when thread starts in AsParallel

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, plinq

The code below will run *ChanceOfWinningMillionDollarJackpot* in separate threads which is pretty cool. However these threads start work right away, whereas, with regular C# Thread class, you get control on when the work start using Thread.Start method. Is there anyway I can get same control when setting up parallel query using AsParallel?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Task<double>[] e = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).AsParallel().Select(n => ChanceOfWinningMillionDollarJackpot(n)).ToArray();
}

private static Task<double> ChanceOfWinningMillionDollarJackpot(int n)
{
    //whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the list as an IEnumerable. Then, only when you query the enumerable the code will actually execute.

```
var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).AsParallel()
    .Select(n => ChanceOfWinningMillionDollarJackpot(n)).AsEnumerable();

var list = enumerable.ToList();
```